# tensorflow evaluate on test set with queques

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

TensorFlow's customer/producer prefetching mechanism is awesome for training.

However, I am not able to find a way to use it for evaluation on test data. We want to go through the test data only and exactly once. But test data is always not dividable by batch size. How should I deal with the remainder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See `eval_in_batches` from [convolutional.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L265) official example. It does most `session.run` calls on regular batch size, while last `session.run` is done on smaller sized batch. This works when you don't hard-code batch-size into your graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is actually how I am doing it. I am just wondering whether we can use TensorFlow's queue prefetching mechanism to do it beautifully without reading in test data from disk and feed it into the graph. Because sometimes the size of test data are also big. Thanks!